# What's the unit for a blueberry?

Tags: measuring-units

What is the unit for a blueberry?
how do you count each blueberries?

> ex) 3 pieces of cake
>       2 slices of pizza
>       5 ?? of blueberry

Edit: Do the following sentences sound natural?

> Blueberries are so expensive in Korea. They cost almost 1$ for 10
>   pieces.

Comment: Exactly the same way as cakes and pizzas: 2 *slices of* blueberry; five blueberries.

Comment: Nobody slices up blueberries. And you are not counting slices anyway. You are counting berries. Luckily, berries are countable. I.e. berries are counted in berries. Five blueberries. $1 for 10 berries.

Comment: @RegDwightАΑA I think that's what I said. Blueberries are assessed in exactly the same way as cakes and pizzas.

Comment: I wondered if there would be a term for each instance of berries. There is a such concept in Korean, Japanese, Chinese, etc. I guess there is no such concept in English. That's probably why this question sounds a little bit bizarre. Thanks!

Comment: Nominated for reopening. The question boils down to "is berry a mass noun or a count noun", but this in *not* something which is given in most dictionaries.

Comment: @Daniel Chinese has measure words for nearly everything (and maybe Japanese and Korean).  English has very few measure words.  We mostly just use units when something is divided up - slices, pieces, parts - when there's a natural grouping - pairs, sets, decks, packs - or when the original word is not countable - dollars, kilograms, liters.

Comment: Outside Korea, small fruit like blueberries are not usually sold by the unit or 10, but by the kilo, or sometimes litre. In fact, I bought two litres of blueberries and a litre of strawberries yesterday.

Comment: @Hugo They sell it by the cups in Korea as well. I was trying to explain to a friend living in US how much expensive blueberries are in Korea.

Comment: A more natural sentence:"Blueberries are so expensive in Korea. 10 of them cost almost $1." Note that when writing out prices, the dollar sign comes first.